# To prevent Finder from showing .noindex files

Tags: terminal, finder, search, unix, indexing

I can restrict Finder searching files by adding .noindex -extension, [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148777/to-exclude-bak-files-in-finders-search). 
However, I want hide those files in Finder search.

**How can you prevent Finder from showing .noindex -files?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to hide things in Mac OS X. Note: if you do any of these you most likely do not need to use the `.noindex` extensions since files hidden from the finder will not be typically be shown in Finder Spotlight searches.

- `chflags hidden fileToHide` (as already mentioned) does this by setting OS X file attributes.
- use the Unix style period at the start of a file name `.fileToHide`, of course this will hide the file from the Finder and the command line.
- create a `.hidden` at the file system root and list the filenames of files to hide from the Finder. This was the way to do it in the first several versions of Mac OS X prior to the chflags method.
- There is also a classic Mac OS 9 file attribute that can hide files, but this should be considered highly depreciated

Note that the various hiding methods and .noindex should all work on Folders too.

Comment: Awesome! I just switched to Zsh and did chflags hidden **/*.bak.noindex; chflags hidden **/*.new. Cleans up my spaces so much. I can now work normally creating bak files. They will just be hidden. I can unhide them when I need them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the command line use:

`chflags hidden fileToHide`

To show files again `chflags nohidden ...`